# Query parameters sent with HttpPut Request not being read properly

Tags: java, uri, httpclient, http-put

I am trying make an HttpPut Request to the server and send some parameters with it, but however I think that the parameters are not being detected due to which the server send an error message. 
My Code is:

```
    URI url = new URI("http://myurl.com/something/something");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPut hput = new HttpPut(utl);
    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",URLEncoder.encode(ppid,"UTF-8")));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",URLEncoder.encode(netid,"UTF-8"))); 
    hput.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
    HttpResponse res = client.execute(hput);
    System.out.println(res.getStatusLine);
```

It says, the PUT method is not supported by the server but the server does support it.
Tried to do a lot research but wasn't successful as most of the posts were just for POST and GET.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the servers PUT and DELETE methods are disabled default. Only GET/POST are enabled.

Comment: Yes, but I have got it confirmed that the server does support PUT method.

Comment: Who confirmed? How they enabled? Did you test it through some other mechanisms to make sure it is enabled?

Comment: Yes, I got it confirmed form the team who handles the server.